# Bootstrap modal horizontal text overflowing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With a large text input inside `<p>` tags the text overflows the bounds of the modal and off the screen requiring a horizontal scrollbar to read.

I've copied the example code from the Bootstrap documentation and simply added a long text string inside the `modal-body` section.  The example on the Bootstrap documentation website seems to word wrap the text correctly but my code does not.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Modal Test</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Details below:</p>
                <p>TEST: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also see exactly what I mean by horizontal overflow on the jsFiddle I created here: http://jsfiddle.net/pX39W/11/

I'm sure it's something simple and I've just been staring at it too long to notice!  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your `TEST:aaaa...` has no spaces and therefore won't wrap.. If you want it to be hidden use `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) property (assuming the text is one long word):

```
.modal-body p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pX39W/12/

Comment: Yes, there's the possibility of having long strings of text so this CSS is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Learned something new today.

Comment: this answer helped me!

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem but my long text is inside a `<td>`. 
Using your jsfiddle (and changing the line `.modal p {` to `.modal td {` does not fix the problem! Is there something different about tables/table cells and wrapping that i need to be aware of?

Comment: Have a look if the <td> has nowrap on.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and works `WRT` screen sizes.

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modalSize{
    min-width: 800px !important;
    background: white;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-content modalSize">
```