# How to constrain content to modal dialog width?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a long string of text in a modal dialog box, but the text does not wrap or stay inside the dialog. How can I fix this? Below is an image and my template for the dialog.

[image]

```
<div class="modal modal-backdrop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{display: shareLinkShowDialog ? 'block' : 'none'}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">
                    Share Link to {{selectedHouseMember.getName()}}
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>{{shareLink}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="toggleShareLinkDialog()">
                    Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word;">
     <p>
        {{shareLink}}
     </p>
</div>
```

Got it working using `word-wrap: break-word;`. I referenced this question: [html - Bootstrap modal horizontal text overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768532/bootstrap-modal-horizontal-text-overflowing)

Answer (score 0):

use

width:100%;
max-width:100%;

to parent

Comment: Do I place this style on modal body?

Comment: yes for modal-body , This problem usually occurs when you have not defined a specific width for the element.

Comment: enter your modal-body css style here

Comment: <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center; max-width: 200px;">
         {{shareLink}}
</div>
I tried your solution and I switched it to this and removed the <p> tags. I would expect the link to stay constrained to 200px but it still did not work.